# How to force an interface to be present at all levels of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, overriding

I have an interface `myIf`, that i would like to have present at all levels of inheritance. The idea is that `fooEverywhere` needs to be at `GrandParent` and `Parent` and further children. So this obvious pattern occurs:

```
  public interface myIf {
    void fooEverywhere ();
  }

  public class GrandParent implements myIf {

    @Override
    public void fooEverywhere() { /* Actions */ }

  }

  public class Parent extends GrandParent implements myIf {
    @Override
    public void fooEverywhere() { super.fooEverywhere(); /* And Other actions */ }
  }
```

However, if i forget / miss `Parent` like this:

```
  public class Parent extends GrandParent /*implements myIf*/ {
//    @Override
//    public void fooEverywhere() { super.fooEverywhere(); /* And Other actions */ }
  }
```

Java, will still be OK, as `parentObject.fooEverywhere()` will find `GrandParent.fooEverywhere()`.

Therefore how can i redesign this to force Java to recognise that `fooEverywhere` must be in `Parent` ?

Comment: I am not sure what are your intentions but the abstract classes are supposed to handle that requirement for you.

Comment: Although I like your question I don't get what your goal is. By extending GrandParent you are implicitly implementing myIf.

Comment: @MarcinKrasowski - There is no guarantee that any of the classes are abstract.

Comment: What Stefan said. -> `force Java to recognise that fooEverywhere must be in Parent`  It already does that.  All classes extending `Parent` must implement `fooEverywhere` (because `Parent` provides an implementation, by default they do).

Comment: @Stefan - I need a different implementation of fooEverywhere() at each class.

Comment: Don't provide a default implementation then.  (In other words, an abstract class that doesn't provide an implementation might be better here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

The longer answer is that you can't because you've already provided an implementation in a class higher in the inheritance chain.  Once it's implemented higher in the chain, it's implemented.

You could create an abstract class as the ancestor which implements the interface and then declare the interface methods as abstract on the abstract ancestor.  Then both GrandParent and Parent would then extend AbstractParent and have to provide their own implementations of the interface methods that were declared as abstract.

Note, interfaces in Java are typically Pascal-case, i.e. MyIf, not myIf.  Also, there is no need to actually use the implements keyword in a descendent class that has a parent already declaring it implements an interface.

Answer (score 1):

As you already said, the compiler does not care as long as as a superclass provides an implementation of the abstract or interface method.

I can hardly imagine any usecase where it it necessary to implement a method in every subclass, but if you really need it you can implement a solution using reflection with `Class#getDeclaredMethods` (only return the methods declared in this class) to validate if each of the classes implements or overrides the method. If not, throw an exception.